# How can i use Roboto font family on my pdf which is generated with puppeteer

Tags: html, css, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

i want to add Roboto font in my pdf which is attached below kindly help me set this font to the pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an edge case where webfonts don't seem to be loaded for PDF rendering, unless you trigger a screenshot first:

```
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

var document = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika);
        body {
          font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
  `

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  let page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setContent(document, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' }) // <= here you should pass the second argument
  await page.pdf({
    path: 'print.pdf',
    format: 'A4'
  })
  browser.close()
})
```

Refrence -

[GITHUB](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/422)

Comment: Load the font as a data uri so that it is included in the html doc